# Mongodb Group into Dictionary style structure

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have the following records:

```
{ id: 1, value : 1, Date: 2016-01-01 },
{ id: 1, value : 2, Date: 2016-01-01 },
{ id: 2, value : 3, Date: 2016-01-01 },
{ id: 3, value : 4, Date: 2016-01-01 }
```

In mongodb C# driver how would I call a collection with this data format to produce something like:

```
 { 
    {
      id: 1, 
      records : [
        {value : 1, Date: 2016-01-01}, 
        {value : 2, Date: 2016-01-01}
    ]}, 
   { 
      id : 2, 
      records : [{value : 3, Date: 2016-01-01}] 
   },
   { 
      id : 3, 
      records : [{value : 4, Date: 2016-01-01}] 
   }
}
```

So i want to group on the "id" field and then return all results grouped by their id as a list. So the structure would be something like C#'s

```
 Dictionary<int, List<MyObj>>
```

Comment: The aggregation framework will be your buddy here; have a look at the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline operator, where you can group the documents by the `id` key and create the `records` array using the [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) operator.

Comment: Isn't this ironic that you use nosql and try to get normalized sql-like output? Maybe you should just rethink your database choice?

Comment: @Stan What about my question is "sql-like"? I don't see the harm in the question... there a lots of reasons to use mongo (or nosql in general) aside from what is shown in this question. Why not try and normalise the data when reading if i would be doing later down the line in code anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised this is an old question... but if anyone comes across it:

I've not got mongo up at the moment to test, but you should be able to use aggregations via linq, something like:

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable()
                      .GroupBy(r => r.Id)
                      .Select(g => new { id = g.Key, records = g.Value });
```

Comment: It is indeed old! So I can't test directly against what i was doing but i think this would work for what i was after...